# Java: Using the Scanner class to read input from a file without pipeing

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader, java.util.scanner, piping

I currently have an implementation of a program where I read in the input using the Scanner class. Integer by integer.
I do this by piping the input file via the command line.

> java program < input.txt

I need to avoid piping the input by using an argument on the command line to open the file in my program.

> java program --file=input.txt

or something similar.
I understand that I could parse the command line argument, extract the text "input.txt" and then use a class like "BufferedReader" or something similar to read the file.

I am just curious if there is away to use the input file (no piping) AND still use the Scanner class.
Which means I wouldn't have to change over my nextInt() and other such calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since arguments are just not evaulated but passed to your `main(String[] args)` method without any work in the middle your only option is to parse the argument, extract the filename `input.txt` and open it as a normal file stream.

I wouldn't see how it should infer that a file must be opened and passed as a pipe without being a pipe.. you can easily use `Scanner` with a `File` argument without bothering about anything..

```
public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException
```

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file. Bytes from the file are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

Comment: Thank you! I based on your suggestion (slightly modified) I have done as I neeeded.

File file = new File("in.txt");
try{
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}